# dart polymer and hangouts_api incompatible versions

Tags: dart, polymer, hangouts-api

I am trying to use dart hangouts_api and polymer at the same time and I get the following error:

> Incompatible version constraints on browser:
>      - hangouts_api 0.3.0 depends on version >=0.9.0 <0.10.0
>      - polymer 0.15.1 depends on version >=0.10.0 <0.11.0

Mu pubspec.yaml file refers to the current version of each.
I cannot use anything but the lastest version of each as the suggested alternatives are years old.  Is there a work around?  To whom should I report this to (assuming it is a bug)?

Answer (score 1):

Just create an issue in the hangouts_api GitHub repo and ask to bring dependencies up to date or even better, create a pull request.

As a workaround you can force a specific version by adding

```
dependency_overrides:
  browser:">=0.10.0“
```

see also https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#dependency-overrides

Comment: Thanks, I created an issue in the hangouts_api repo.  At this early stage in my dart education, I don't have a clue how to modify their package, but thanks for the work-around!